# Mule 4 How to configure multiple scheduling strategies

Tags: mule4

Is it possible to configure multiple scheduling strategies/cron jobs in Mule 4. One for week days and another totally different for week ends in Mule 4. In Mule 3.X we could you composite source. Thanks.

```
<scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="43278bf8-40f1-45bf-b20a-5e1f53c535ba" >
    <scheduling-strategy >
        <cron expression="0 0 6 ? * MON-FRI *" />
    </scheduling-strategy>          
</scheduler>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [migration guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/migration-core) suggests, just create two different flows each with its own scheduler. Then have each flow do a flow-ref to the flow with the logic.